# Большой вопрос?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

Что делать, если в вопросе необходимо представить полный код, но он превышает по объему допустимый системой: `Максимальная длина тела 30000 символов`?
При этом сторонние ресурсы `jsfiddle` и `codepen` участниками сообщества категорично не приветствуются.

Comment: Упрощать код до разумного размера. Все равно никто не будет разбираться в 30 килобайтах кода, чтобы найти ошибку.

Comment: Разумный размер - это подпадающий под понятие "[минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" (ключевое слово - "минимальный").

Comment: а в чем суть вопроса, если нужно больше 30000 символов? Действительно ли необходим такой большой кусок кода? Действительно ли на jsfiddle тоже использовано больше 30000 символов?

Comment: на первый взгляд кажется, что идет попытка вставить текст какой-то библиотеки вместо подключения ее с внешнего источника, но не совсем уверен

Comment: речь про этот вопрос? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1057433/186999

Comment: @Sevastopol, если речь про вопрос указанный в моем комментарии я напишу что нужно сделать

Comment: @Sevastopol', в каждом отдельном случае нужно разбираться отдельно. В приведенном вопросе одно решение, в каком-то другом - второе

Comment: В большинстве случаев проблема довольно быстро локализуется до уровня достаточного для вставки в вопрос.

Comment: @Sevastopol', написал ответ.

Comment: А и не надо сохранять **все** проблемные моменты. По правилам ресурса, один вопрос - одна проблема. И опять же, по той ссылке приведены 2 способа сокращения кода. Ну а вообще, @Grundy вон все правильно ответил. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В каждом отдельном случае нужно разбираться отдельно.

В большинстве случаев проблема довольно быстро локализуется до уровня достаточного для вставки в вопрос.

---

Для примера можно рассмотреть вопрос [Не работает canvas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1057433/186999). <sub>(стоит подумать над более конкретным заголовком вопроса)</sub>

Проблема с файлом `script_app.js`, который подключается отдельно и который из-за размера нельзя вставить непосредственно в вопрос.

Если посмотреть содержимое данного файла можно заметить

1. файл является результатом сборки
2. содержит в себе полифиллы от бабеля
3. несколько библиотек, предположительно для работы с canvas и svg/анимацией

выделить пользовательский код от кода библиотек с ходу не получилось.

---

Что необходимо сделать:

1. Вместо собранного файла прикладывать **исходник** файла
2. Библиотеки подключать с внешних источников

В этом случае не будет лишнего кода от сборки и можно будет анализировать непосредственно написанный код.

Если пользовательский код отсутствует в принципе, то стоит как минимум указать используемые библиотеки и, опять же, подключить их с внешних источников.